# Is my proof here correct (basic real analysis/order theory question)?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, elementary-set-theory, order-theory, supremum-and-infimum

I'm self-studying real analysis and came across a simple problem I was trying to solve (although I think this is more of an order theory problem):

> Let $A\subseteq \mathbb{R}$ so that $ε\:>0$ and $\forall \alpha \in A:\alpha >\:ε$
>
> Show that the greatest lower bound (infimum) of $A$ is not $0$.

Pardon me if the language is somewhat imprecise, I translated this question to English and I'm not yet fully proficient in English mathematical terminology.

Anyway, I solved this question in the following way: since all elements of set $A$ are bigger than $ε$, I figured out that $Inf A=ε$, and since $ε>0$, we can use transitivity to conclude that $Inf A > 0$, and therefore $Inf A  \neq 0$.∎

Is my proof correct and acceptable? Because in the solutions file, the author of the question did something different and proved it by contradiction.

Thank you very much :)

Comment: This is not quite correct. What we can claim is that $\inf(A)\geq\varepsilon$, but we cannot say that equality holds.

Comment: @Dave but why? In my understanding, the infimum is the greatest number $m$ which satisfies $\forall \alpha \in A\::\:\alpha \ge m$, and since all elements in the set $A$ are bigger than $ ε$, it seems like the greatest possible lower bound is $ε$ itself. Or is any of this wrong?

Comment: What we know about $\varepsilon$ is that it is a lower bound for the set $A$. However, we do not know that $\varepsilon$ is the **greatest** lower bound for $A$. For example, if $A=\{3,4,5\}$ and $\varepsilon=1>0$, then the conditions posed in the problem are satisfied, but $\varepsilon=1$ is certainly not the infimum of $A$ (indeed, $3$ is the infimum).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Dave points in a comment, you can conclude that $\inf A \geq \varepsilon$, yielding 
$\inf A \geq \varepsilon > 0,$
whence $\inf A > 0$.

Why can't you conclude that $\inf A = \varepsilon$?
Well, suppose, for example that $A=\{2\}$ and $\varepsilon=1$.
Then $\inf A = 2$.
Of course you still have that $\inf A > 0$, which is what you wanted to prove.

Comment: Thank you. So showing that $Inf A >0$ is a sufficient proof?

Comment: @Blabla Yes. If $\inf A > 0$, then $\inf A \neq 0$, because it is **not** the case that $0>0$.

Answer (score 1):

Your proof is incorrect because you assume $\inf{A} = \epsilon$.

Here's a proof.  Suppose $\inf{A} = 0$.  Let $\epsilon > 0$.  Since $\inf{A}$ is the infimum, there exists an element $\alpha \in A$ such that $\inf{A} + \epsilon  = \epsilon > \alpha$, contradicting the hypothesis.